# What's the best way to gear up for heroics in Mists of Pandaria?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have just reached 90 and my gearscore is way short of the one required for heroics. I am just wondering whether there is another way to improve my gearscore without having to grind reputation points with the various MoP factions?

Even if I eventually manage to get the reputation required to buy JP gear, then how do I go about earning JP? I can no longer randomly queue normal dungeons at 90 (I can manually select them, but that doesn't give me the seven times per week JP bonus). Essentially I am in a bit of limbo.

According to this unhelpful comment by [Manbullpig](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/6794870009?page=1#7), apparently it only takes 15 minutes to gear up for heroics at 90. I am not quite sure whether he was exaggerating or if it's true.

Comment: I did a heroic a few minutes after hitting 90 with just quest gear from Dread Wastes. They are much easier than the heroics at the launch of Cataclysm. I'd say continue your quest line until your average gear level is high enough then queue up - you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: I will probably just continue with the quest lines. I am almost @ the gs level required to start doing scenarios. Hopefully that will give me enough gs for heroics.

Comment: Pick yourself up some JC rings or JC necklaces from the AH. I'm talking about the ones that jewel crafters are currently making for MoP. The item level is 450 for the rings and necklaces, and the price shouldn't be too bad, but you can expect to find prices anywhere from 1k to 2k (at least that's where they're sitting at on my server).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Players are expected to gather gear pre-heroics from:

- Questing, especially completing long questing chains around level 89 and 90 that reward a blue
- Doing normal dungeons at level 88 through 90. There is enough blue gear here to do heroics in.
- Cashing in any Justice points from level 85 at the justice point vendor (no reputation required*)
- Grinding out reputation with factions that award blue gear at honored (not that much of a grind).
- Doing Scenarios at level 90, there is a ring of valor style scenario that rewards a blue weapon (Arena of Annihilation)

If your falling short, you might have abandoned long quest chains too early, or didn't do any dungeons (or just got unlucky). Dungeon quests themselves reward a guaranteed couple of blues as a reward for their first playthrough.

**source: [Patch 5.0.5 October 1st Hotfixes](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/blog/7207170): Players no longer require Honored reputation with Mists of Pandaria factions to purchase gear with Justice Points.*

Comment: Craftet pvp items are also a good way to boost your item level if you are not going to tank, they can be relative cheap and are ilevel 450 making them as good as non heroic drops

Comment: Just so you guys know, there is no real justice point or valor point vendor sitting in the main faction cities anymore. To spend the those points you need to have friendly, honored, revered, or exalted to get access to most of the justice and valor point items. So it recommended that you do your dailies and complete zone quests to maximize your rep before dailies

Comment: A time sensitive option as well: Queue up for Brewfest, the boss drops a variety of ilevel 470 trinkets.

Comment: Yes, but he's insanely hard this year and most pug's can't do him and give up before figuring out the strategy.

Answer (score 1):

You need ilevel 435 for Heroic Dungeons.

Based on this [article](http://www.wowpedia.org/Item_level), the easiest options are:

```
ilevel 435 Gate of Setting Sun / Shado-Pan Monastary (normal)
ilevel 437 Dread Wastes quest rewards (green)
ilevel 442 Townlong Steppes quests rewards (blue)
ilevel 450 Dread Wastes quests rewards (blue)  <--- start here if you are 90
ilevel 458 Justice Points / Honor Points
ilevel 463 Scenarios  (requires ilevel 425 for entry)
```

Check the auction house for BoE world drops and level 90 crafted gear.
There's also BoA archaeology gear.

Also the Sha of Anger drops a one time quest item you can turn in for a set of epic boots. And killing Galleon has a chance for you to get raid gear from Galleon and Sha of Anger each week

Comment: Are the BoA archaeology items still a time-sink like they were in Cataclysm? I knew guys that spent a couple of hundred hours but came away with none of the BoA weapons. That coupled with the fact that they were quickly deprecated when the next big patch came out (with better item level gear) made the whole BoA thing seem to be nothing but a waste of time.

Comment: There is a mastery trinket, a caster offhand, and a polearm... all ilevel 463.  After two hours of surveying, I have 2 out of 3.  If you need a trinket - arch may be the answer.

Comment: I have been continuing my quests in Townlong and Dread Wastes. I managed to get enough ilvl last night to start on Scenarios. Thanks for the pointers however!

Comment: How high does your item level have to be for scenarios?